# Retrieving information about an Image

Tags: java, image, mime-types, dimensions

Good day,

Anybody knows of a good java library for retrieving mime type and dimension of a jpeg, gif, and png image file in java?

I tried javax.imageio.ImageIO but it seems that there are some image files that it can't handle (i.e. images created with adobe photoshop).

Thanks,
Franz

Comment: As you can see in the documentation for package javax.imageio, it by default supports a limited set of file formats: JPEG, PNG, BMP, WBMP, GIF. So it shouldn't have been a suprise that Photoship files (PSD) don't work.

Comment: Actually, most of my problems are with JPEGs created by photoshop. Although the magic bytes are the same as that of a regular JPEG, the file format is different (i.e. compared to a JPEG created from MSPaint or GIMP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Apache Sanselan](http://incubator.apache.org/sanselan/site/index.html) for the dimension and [Droid](http://droid.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Introduction) for the identification.

Comment: Apache Sanselan works like a charm ! :-)

..Didn't try Droid though. I need image specific operations.